# How to read a directory with using InputStream in eclipse plugin developement

Tags: eclipse, plugins, directory, inputstream

I'm developing an eclipse plug-in and I need to traverse a directory and whole content of the directory. I found the method which reads a file in plug-in (bundleresource) as InputStream.

```
InputStream stream = Activator.class.getResourceAsStream("/dir1/dir2/file.ext");
```

this method works for files only. I need a way to read directories, list subdirectories and files like File.io.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to read a resource directory of your plugin? Otherwise you have to traverse a directory and open one stream per file:

```
    String path = "c:\\temp\\";
    File directory = new File(path);
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        String[] list = directory.list();
        for (String entry : list) {
            String absolutePath = path + entry;
            System.out.println("processing " + absolutePath);
            File file = new File(absolutePath);
            if (file.isFile()) {
                FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
                // use stream
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to traverse subdirectories as well you should wrap this into a recursive method, check if `file` is a directory and call the recursive method in this case.

Comment: In plug-in directories, you can't use file protocol (or File.IO)
when I install plug-in to eclipse, resourcebundle protocol is used as file system. having path is useless cause when I tried to get path of a folder in plug-in, I get something like: "/resourcebundle//173/documents/templateproject.properties"  and File IO does not accept this path. I want to traverse some directory without having constant file locations. Need a parent-child relation of directories or something else

Comment: Traversing a resource directory is not possible as far as I know.